# Flipkart.com image src is changing after scraping

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

**So I was trying to scrape flipcart.com for pure learning purpose & I'm facing a problem,can't understand why. I was trying to scrape image src from this link - https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=sofa & after I found in dev tools that the src was-**

```
<img class="_396cs4 _3exPp9" alt="Muebles Casa Croma Leatherette 3 Seater  Sofa" src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/612/612/jvtujrk0/sofa-sectional/z/w/h/light-brown-na-colton-letheratte-light-brown-three-seater-sofa-original-imafghzgwdznm33t.jpeg?q=70">
```

**but when I tried to scrape that in scrapy shell I got different -**

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//div[@class="CXW8mj _21_khk"]/img/@src').get()
Out[1]: '//img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/placeholder_fcebae.svg'
```

**Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem, or why the src is changing.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use selenium get the data. The image data is loaded dynamically. Here is use scrapy.Selector and [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to extract the data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
browser.get(url="https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=sofa")

page = browser.page_source
image_data = Selector(text=page)
print(image_data.xpath('//div[@class="CXW8mj _21_khk"]/img/@src').get())
```

output

```
https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/612/612/jyeq64w0/sofa-sectional/u/k/b/blue-na-56101502sd00927-godrej-interio-blue-original-imaffpsrybgrhvxb.jpeg?q=70
```

note: You need to install selenium if not installed in your system.